# How do i play .vob videos on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, video, vlc

I am trying to play Iron Man 1 on my lubuntu system, I installed VLC, but it won't play it. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In terminal:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Make sure to allow installation of ms-fonts via your keyboard tab.

After that VLC should VOB.